# How to set up a domain?

Tags: dns, blogs, record

I have blog ( http://n7a.ziqu.de/Homepages/whitebyte/wordpress/ )

And now I bought a domain ( http://whitebyte.info/ ) here http://www.inwx.de/

At inwx.de they gave me the option to use a frame to forward visitors to my site.

But I think there must be a better way without frames. Can you help me?

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/vhosts/name-based.html

Answer (score 1):

If you want the URL to stay visible as http://whitebyte.info either use the frame, or host the site with its own ip. Else forward http://whitebyte.info/ to http://n7a.ziqu.de/Homepages/whitebyte/wordpress/